# Getting a property of an object within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js

I use Vue.js and have a method that compares a value from one array with a value from another array.

```
array1:  [{ name: 'test1', somevar: true }, { name: 'test2', somevar: false }]
array2: ['test1', 'test3']

  compare() {
    //I want to access an object property within an array1
    this.array1.forEach((element) => {
      if(this.array1.element.name.includes(this.array2[0])) {
        // if it is true, I would like to remove that compared value from an array 1
        if(this.array2[0] !== -1) {
          var index = this.array1.element.name.indexOf(this.array2[0])
          this.array1.splice(index, 1)
        }
      }
```

I think this part: `this.array1.forEach((element)` is incorrect. How can I access property of that object?

Comment: `if (element.name...)` no need for `this.array1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array1` is an array, not an object, so accessing `this.array1.element` won't work. Simply refrence the element as the parmeter given to `forEach` instead.

Also, the function passed `forEach` accepts another argument: the second argument represents the *current element's index*, so there's no need to search for `indexOf`.

But, even better than those tweaks, it would be more appropriate to use `filter` in this situation:

```js
const obj = {
  array1:  [{ name: 'test1', somevar: true }, { name: 'test2', somevar: false }],
  array2: ['test1', 'test3'],
  compare() {
    obj.array1 = obj.array1.filter(({ name }) => (
      !obj.array2.includes(name)
    ))
  }
}
obj.compare();
console.log(obj.array1);
```

Comment: I think changing `!element.name.includes(obj.array2[0])` to `!obj.array2.includes(element.name)` would make more sense as he wantst o remove items from `array1` whose name is present in `array2`.

Comment: Thank you! And how do I refrence the element as the parmeter in that `forEach` function?

Comment: Eg `this.array1.forEach((element, i) => {` then the index of the current element being iterated over is `i`. (Don't try to mutate an array while iterating over it though)

Comment: I still cannot access that object property `name` inside of an array.

Comment: Instead of `if(this.array1.element.name.includes(this.array2[0])) {`, I tried `if(element[i].name.includes(this.array2[0])) {` but still doesn't work.

Comment: @kabugh Just press "Run code snippet" - you should be able to see that it works just fine as is.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I was wondering if something like this would be possible.
`this.array1.forEach((element, i) => {`
     `if(element[i].name.includes(this.array2[0])) { console.log('it works') })`

Comment: @kabugh `element` is the array item, not the array - just `console.log` it, should be pretty obvious. (so, accessing `element[i]` doesn't make any sense, just access `element`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173446/discussion-between-kabugh-and-certainperformance).